# CentOS: eth0 not starting on boot

Tags: networking, centos, eth0

Whenever I reboot a CentOS Hyper-V VM, `eth0` does not start automatically. All I need to do is perform `ifup eth0` and all is fixed, but that isn't feasible from ssh! I am starting in runlevel 3.

---

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/*release*
CentOS release 6.2 (Final)
```

---

After I perform `ifup eth0` on the console:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:5D:2B:2B:07
      inet addr:10.10.0.3  Bcast:10.10.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::215:5dff:fe2b:2b07/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:34 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:49 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:4656 (4.5 KiB)  TX bytes:6399 (6.2 KiB)
      Interrupt:9 Base address:0xa000
```

---

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=10.10.0.3
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=10.10.0.1
USERCTL=no
ONBOOT=yes
```

---

```
[root@localhost ~]# chkconfig --list | grep network
network         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

---

After trying to turn off Network Manager

```
[root@localhost ~]# chkconfig NetworkManager off
error reading information on service NetworkManager: No such file or directory
[root@localhost ~]# service NetworkManager status
NetworkManager: unrecognized service
```

---

The most recent clean boot

```
[root@localhost ~]# grep eth0 /var/log/messages
Jul  7 02:12:44 localhost kernel: eth0: Digital DS21140 Tulip rev 32 at MMIO 0xfebff000, 00:15:5d:2b:2b:07, IRQ 9.
Jul  7 02:13:15 localhost kernel: eth0: Using EEPROM-set media 100baseTx-FDX.

[root@localhost ~]# dmesg | grep eth0
eth0: Digital DS21140 Tulip rev 32 at MMIO 0xfebff000, 00:15:5d:2b:2b:07, IRQ 9.
eth0: Using EEPROM-set media 100baseTx-FDX.
eth0: no IPv6 routers present
```

---

The only problems I have EVER seen, is when I do the command of `ifup eth0` I get the following errors, but `eth0` still gets started:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ifup eth0
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-ipv6: line 56: /etc/sysconfig/network: No such file or directory
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-aliases: line 125: /etc/sysconfig/network: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Which CentOS release? 5.x or 6.x?

Comment: it is centos 6.2

Comment: Somewhat related to "Bringing up interface eth0: Device eth0 does not seem to be present, delaying initialization [FAILED]" issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hmm.  From your last message, look for the `/etc/sysconfig/network` file.

I have:

```
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network
NETWORKING=yes
```

You can also have (on my CentOS 5 box):

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=foo.example.org
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
```

Documentation is [here](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-sysconfig.html#s2-sysconfig-network) (at least for 5, which should be very similar)

I'm not sure what the default is for the "NETWORKING" setting.  It's possible it's "no" and that's why it's not starting on boot.

Comment: you got it!
thanks a million. file didnt exist, a quick touch and vi did the trick.

Comment: How was this missing on your system? Running `system-config-network` after the initial installation would get things in the right place if they weren't defined during the installation process.

Answer (score 7):

Open `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` file and replace line

```
ONBOOT=no
```

with

```
ONBOOT=yes
```

save and exit the file, and restart the linux system.

Answer (score 3):

Disable the `NetworkManager` service with `chkconfig` or `ntsysv` and see if that helps.

If it's not running, check your /var/log/boot.log, `dmesg` and /var/log/messages. Following a clean boot, `grep eth0 /var/log/messages` or `dmesg | grep eth0` should give you an idea of what's happening.

Is this a new VM or a cloned system (P2V)?

Comment: I have updated the ticket with the output of trying to stop the service

Comment: Oh, that can be a problem in some cases. See my update.

Comment: this is a new vm

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a headless Centos8 on my rpi. The config file in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` is accurate according to DHCP protocols, however, each time I rebooted I got "Ethernet not found". My fix was changing to static network config.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in the folder `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` you have only the relevant files, and no others!

Take special care with `vi` editor or similar that create backup files ended with ~

When this happens, I've seen some linux distros failing to bring up some interfaces at boot.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a Legacy Network Adapter, which is an emulated Intel e1000 GB Nic.  This fixed the issue for me of Centos not automatically starting networking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer FoxDeploy that solve the issue for me thank u a lot